# Add UIView to Storyboard without a XIB file

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to add a UIView without a nib file to the storyboard. I have dragged a UIView onto the storyboard and changed it's class to "Jahreskalender" with the Jahreskalender class as follows:

```
 class Jahreskalender: UIView {

 override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
     // Drawing code
     self.opaque = false
     self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 100, green: 1, blue: 5, alpha: 0)
     let jahresView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Calender.png"))
     jahresView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
     self.addSubview(jahresView)
   }
}
```

When I run the app all I get is a black rectangle where I have dragged the UIView.
Do I need to load a XIB file or can I do everything with the "Jahreskalender" class programmaticall? Looked everywhere but can't find any tutorials.

Comment: UIView or UIViewController ? because you can directly add UIView in your controller

Comment: UIView. I am attempting to add the UIView to a UIViewController.

Comment: Is it possible to drop a UIView in storyboard without using any controller???

Comment: Sorry I am unclear with my explanations. I am using a storyboard and within it am using a View Controller. I dragged a UIView onto the View Controller. Then I defined the class of the UIView to be "Jahreskalender".

Comment: Did you set the UIView constraints?

Comment: Do you mean programmatically? I don't believe this matters as all I see is a black box.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some more trial and error I found my mistake. I need to call init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder).

```
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.opaque = false
        }
```

Now it works. Thanks for the tips!